# Dispatch Group for nested loop

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, share-extension

I've share extension with multiple user list and I can select many user and multiple image to all selected user. For that I used dispatch group and there are two loop 1 for all users and inside that loop for all selected images.

```
let myGroup = DispatchGroup()
let myGroupMain = DispatchGroup()
let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
dispatchQueue.async {
for indexPath in self.indexPathContain  {
 myGroupMain.enter()

 for (index, attachment) in (content.attachments as! [NSItemProvider]).enumerated() {
   myGroup.enter()
  let paramDict = [
   "id":"0",
   "chat_id":modelList.id!,
   "sender_id":  x,
   "image":"",
   "receiver_id": modelList.sender_id!,
   "type": "1",
   "message": "",
   "file":dataArr,
   ] as [String : Any]
   self?.socket?.emit("upload_files", paramDict)
    myGroup.leave()
 }
 myGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            myGroupMain.leave()
        }
}
 myGroupMain.notify(queue: .main) {

       self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
                print(i)
           }

}
```

In above case when I execute then it will **myGroupMain.notify** without complete **myGroup** loop completion.
Swift 5/Xcode 11.3

Answer (score 0):

Earlier, I have faced the same issue. I fixed the issue by defining `myGroup` and `myGroupMain` globally.

Please refer below code.

```
class ClassName {

    let myGroup = DispatchGroup()
    let myGroupMain = DispatchGroup()
    let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)

    func yourCode(){
        dispatchQueue.async {
            for indexPath in self.indexPathContain  {
                myGroupMain.enter()

                for (index, attachment) in (content.attachments as! [NSItemProvider]).enumerated() {
                    myGroup.enter()
                    let paramDict = [
                        "id":"0",
                        "chat_id":modelList.id!,
                        "sender_id":  x,
                        "image":"",
                        "receiver_id": modelList.sender_id!,
                        "type": "1",
                        "message": "",
                        "file":dataArr,
                        ] as [String : Any]
                    self?.socket?.emit("upload_files", paramDict)
                    myGroup.leave()
                }
                myGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
                    myGroupMain.leave()
                }
            }
            myGroupMain.notify(queue: .main) {

                self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
                print(i)
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: I debug and found loop is working fine, I think sockt.emit not send request to server. In server console i did not see request for all. only for 1 image it is showing request on server console.